# Exporting express params to a global file

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a list of url params that I'm using with express.

Now I'm trying to put this in an external file so they can be used though-out the whole app, the param works when it's in the file but not when it's external.

I looked though the documentation but it lacks anything about catching all params.

The main app that has many different API routes.

```
var routeParams = require('./route_params.js');
app.param(routeParams);
```

The params file that needs to be used globally though-out the app.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

require('./models/User');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

//UserId param.
router.param('userid', function(req, res, next, id) 
{
  var query = User.findById(id);
  query.exec(function (err, user)
  {
    if(err)
    {
        res.json(err);
    }
    else if(!user)
    {
        res.json({message:'User does not exist'});
    }
    else
    {
        req.userid = user;
        return next();
    }

  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: did you include the external file router in your express app. ```app.use(router)```

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work.